# Query select max

Tags: mysql, select, max, sql-order-by

**I have this table**

```
+----+-----+---------+
| id | id2 | correct |
+----+-----+---------+
|  1 |   5 |       0 |
|  2 |   4 |       0 |
|  3 |   5 |       1 |
|  4 |   5 |       1 |
|  5 |   4 |       0 |
|  6 |   2 |       1 |
|  7 |   4 |       0 |
|  8 |   2 |       0 |
|  9 |   2 |       0 |
|  10|   5 |       1 |
|  11|   5 |       1 |
+----+-----+---------+
```

I need to select the id2 ordering the maximum value of how many time the "correct" answer "0" appears for each id2. 
I'll give you an example.
*The id2: 2 - appears 3 times and 2 times out of 3 with a a correct of "0".


The id2: 4 - appears 3 times and 3 times out of 3 with a correct of "0".


The id2: 5 - appears 5 times and 1 times out of 5 with a correct of "0".*

So I want to order the id2 "4" before of the id2 of "2", and the id2 "5" as the last one.

Sorry for my bad explanation but I have no clue of how to do that.

Thank you in advance for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id2
from mytable
where correct = 0
group by id2
order by count(*) desc
```

If you also want to include ids with no correct answer:

```
select id2
from mytable
group by id2
order by sum(correct = 0) desc
```